# distorm64 confuses bx with ebx

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I have the following code to decode the bytes 0x66 0x5b 0xc3 (pop ebx / ret) with distorm64 (code was taken from [this](http://code.google.com/p/distorm/source/browse/trunk/examples/win32/main.cpp) example)

```
    // Holds the result of the decoding.
    _DecodeResult res;
    // Decoded instruction information.
    _DecodedInst decodedInstructions[MAX_INSTRUCTIONS];
    // next is used for instruction's offset synchronization.
    // decodedInstructionsCount holds the count of filled instructions' array by the decoder.
    unsigned int decodedInstructionsCount = 0, i, next;

    // Default decoding mode is 32 bits, could be set by command line.
    _DecodeType dt;
    if(!x64)
        dt = Decode32Bits;
    else
        dt = Decode64Bits;

    // Default offset for buffer is 0, could be set in command line.
    _OffsetType offset = 0;
    char* errch = NULL;
    char tempBuf[500];

    // Decode the buffer at given offset (virtual address).
    while (1) 
    {
        // If you get an unresolved external symbol linker error for the following line,
        // change the SUPPORT_64BIT_OFFSET in distorm.h.
        res = distorm_decode(offset, (const unsigned char*)byteCodeBuffer, byteCodeBufferSize, dt, decodedInstructions, MAX_INSTRUCTIONS, &decodedInstructionsCount);
        if (res == DECRES_INPUTERR) 
        {
            // Null buffer? Decode type not 16/32/64?
            printf("Input error, halting!");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < decodedInstructionsCount; i++) 
        {
#ifdef SUPPORT_64BIT_OFFSET
            sprintf_s(tempBuf, 500, "%0*I64x (%02d) %-24s %s%s%s\n", dt != Decode64Bits ? 8 : 16, decodedInstructions[i].offset, decodedInstructions[i].size, (char*)decodedInstructions[i].instructionHex.p, (char*)decodedInstructions[i].mnemonic.p, decodedInstructions[i].operands.length != 0 ? " " : "", (char*)decodedInstructions[i].operands.p);
            outputText.append(tempBuf);
#else
            printf("%08x (%02d) %-24s %s%s%s\n", decodedInstructions[i].offset, decodedInstructions[i].size, (char*)decodedInstructions[i].instructionHex.p, (char*)decodedInstructions[i].mnemonic.p, decodedInstructions[i].operands.length != 0 ? " " : "", (char*)decodedInstructions[i].operands.p);
#endif
        }

        if (res == DECRES_SUCCESS) break; // All instructions were decoded.
        else if (decodedInstructionsCount == 0) break;

        // Synchronize:
        next = (unsigned long)(decodedInstructions[decodedInstructionsCount-1].offset - offset);
        next += decodedInstructions[decodedInstructionsCount-1].size;
        // Advance ptr and recalc offset.
        byteCodeBuffer += next;
        byteCodeBufferSize -= next;
        offset += next;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

the result is

```
00000000 (02) 665b                     POP BX
00000002 (01) c3                       RET
```

which is wrong since the register isn't BX but EBX.

If I try to compile (with nasm) the "pop bx / ret" sequence, I get 0x5b 0xc3 and distorm translates it into

```
00000000 (01) 5b                       POP EBX
00000001 (01) c3                       RET
```

which is equally wrong (not EBX, but BX should be returned!)

Where am I getting wrong? Is it a distorm64 bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

66 5b is POP BX when the processor is in 32-bit mode (and an invalid opcode in 64-bit mode, as only "whole" 64-bit registers can be pushed and popped in 64-bit mode). If you are disassembling 16-bit code with a 32-bit disassembler, then you can expect wrong results.

Note that the 66 prefix "toggles" the 32/16-bit flag for one instruction, so if you have 32-bit code, 66 turns the next instruction to a 16-bit one, and if you have 16-bit code, it turns it into a 32-bit instruction.

So I can only assume there is some confusion as to what mode your code is in - and that the disassembler is interpreting something that is 16-bit code as 32-bit code, or something like thiat.

Comment: Could this depend by the fact that I recompiled with Visual Studio the .lib distorm64 project in 64 bit mode?

Comment: `66 5b` **is** `POP BX` even in 64 bit mode, and it works without invalid opcode exception (try it). However it will change the stack pointer by 2 and that's likely to blow up something else unless special care is taken.

Comment: @Jester: Ok, "not very usable" then, as 64-bit mode wants the stack aligned to 8 bytes. Certainly not usable in kernel mode (where I do a lot of my work...)

Comment: @Johnny - what was the code you disassembled produced by. I still think you are feeding in 16-bit code.

Comment: And you were right.. it seems that nasm defaults to 16 bit. By using the "bits 32" directive before the 32 bit code I managed to solve it. Thank you!